# checking beforing inserting in db - php

Tags: php

I'm just using a comment box for letting user to enter the comments, but now the user is tending to post as many comment, I just want the user to post only one time, So wat i think is before we inserting a comment in database we will check something to stop inserting one more time (Dont let place twice the same comment)

```
$query = "INSERT INTO comments(user_id,post_id,comments)"
            ."VALUES('".$user_id."','" .$post_id. "','" .$comment_text. "')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error'.mysql_error());
```

Comment: ur question is not clear. u want same user to not save comments continously or same comments to be posted twice.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I hope you are sanitizing your input from the user, if not, please please please do.

I think the best way to solve this is to check if the previous comment is the same as the comment the user is currently inserting, say something like this

```
$query = "SELECT comment_text FROM comments WHERE user_id=$user_id ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 1;"
```

And then check if the comment text is the same

```
if($comment_text != $previous_text) {
    //insert new comment
}
```

Another alternative is to prevent the user from posting a comment within a certain amount of time, similar to this site. 30seconds is usually the average. Then you would do a check based on a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Issue might be due to slow (ajax) response on submitting comment. So user might be pressing submit button multiple times. So best thing to do is in the submit handler you disable the button , so no further submits of same comment happend.

Also if users are intentionally submitting same data you might want to check the IP adrress of user and if comments are comming from same IP within short time span consider it as spam and restrict it .

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicates, I suggest you use client side javascript to [disable the submit button](http://www.webreference.com/js/tips/020201.html)  after it is clicked.

Your SQL is not important here, but ensure you sanitize it as ohmusama mentioned.